# how to like/unlike with button using toggleclass

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, ajax

this is my like button...

**HTML code**

```
<div class="btn"> 
  <div class="boxcoracao">
    <span class="coracao" id = "<?php echo $postid?>" name = "like">br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Love</span>
  </div>
</div>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
```

**Jquery inside HTML**

```
<script>
 $(".btn ").click(function(){ 
   $('.boxcoracao .coracao', this).toggleClass("ativo"); 
}); 
</script>
```

it works when i click and unclick the button the button changes but what my problem is how can i use this function to save data to my database. sample when 1st click the button it will like.. and when i click the button again it will unlike. can you help me how to query this ?

**like table**

```
postid  |  postmember |  likeid   
   50          12           1
```

postid by the name itself the id of the post..
postmember is the id of the user who posted sample user 12 posted and the id is 50..
likeid is the user who likes the post of the other user sample user 1 like the post of user 12..

Comment: `if ($(this).hasClass("ativo")) { ...`

Comment: If your likeid is going to store many people in the one column (like an array of user ids) then you would want to remove that persons id from the likeid array. If I am understanding that correctly. For example if 5 people like the post it will be like postid = 50  |  postmember = 12 |  likeid = 1, 22, 1001, 21, 44. If I wanted to click unlike then and If i was logged in as member 22, then likeid would = 1, 1001, 21, 44. Is that Correct?

Comment: this will happen if many user like the post in the database For example if 5 people like the post

postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 1
postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 22
postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 1001
postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 21
postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 44 


this is the only idea have right now. to store the data..and your example is confusing me. like how can i store an array of data inside 1 column.. sorry im really new in this field so this is the only way i have right now..

Comment: thank you so much these is what i really need but i got another problem when i refresh the page the post that i like before was not liked...

Comment: When you first load the page you would need to query your database and just do a simple count to see how many likes there are for the post id. There are many ways to do this but a simple search for php count will give you some detailed answers. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ajax would be an option.

```js
$("#postWrapper").on("click", ".likeToggle", function(){
 
 // grabe the variables you need

 var postid = $("#postid").attr("data-postid"); //postid
 var postmember = $("#postmember").attr("data-postmember"); // postmember
 var likeid = $("#likeid").attr("data-likeid"); // likeid

  $(this).toggleClass("likeColor");
  
  if ($(this).hasClass("likeColor")){
    
    console.log("LIKE");    
    $(this).text("dislike"); // update the text to show what the next click would be
    togglePost("like", postid, postmember,likeid); // run function
    
  } else {
  
    console.log("DISLIKE");
    $(this).text("like"); // update the text to show what the next click would be
    togglePost("dislike", postid, postmember,likeid); // run function
    
  }
 // send ajax to process.php

 
 function togglePost(action, postid, postmember, likeid){
 
  $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "action="+action+"&postid="+postid+"&postmember="+postmember+"&likeid="+likeid,
        success: function(data){
         
         alert("success");
          
        },
        error: function(e){
         alert("error");
        }
      });
      

 }

  });
```

```css
.likeColor {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- index.php -->
<div id="postWrapper">
  <span id='postid' data-postid="50">POST ID: 50</span>
  <span id='postmember' data-postmember="12">CREATED BY: 12</span><br><br>
  <p>post contents are written here....</p><br>
  <br><hr><br>
  <div id='likeid' data-likeid="10">currently LOGGED IN as Member: 10</div><br>
 
  <button class="likeToggle">like</button>
</div>

<!-- process.php -->
<!--

  /*
  // you need to add 1 more row here and call it id and make it autoincrement INT or inserts wont work.
  
id = 1 | postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 1
id = 2 | postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 22
id = 3 | postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 1001
id = 4 | postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 21
id = 5 |postid = 50 | postmember = 12 | likeid = 44
*/

   $action = $_POST['action'];
   $likeid = $_POST['likeid'];
   $postmember= $_POST['postmember'];
   $postid = $_POST['postid']

 UpdateLikes($postid, $postmember, $likeid, $action);
  
 function UpdateLikes($postid, $postmember, $likeid, $action){
  
 if ($action == "dislike"){
  $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM liketable WHERE 
   postid = '$postid' &&
   likeid = '$likeid'
   ");
 } else {
  
  // before inserting you might want to check if they alredy liked or not before adding their count again.
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO liketable
   ( postid,  postmember, likeid ) VALUES 
     ('$postid','$postmember','$likeid')");
 }
  
  }

  -->
```

Comment: can you tell me the condition/if statement on the process.php??i think thats what i need the most..i just dont know how to do it...

Comment: I updated and tested it. I made a column in my database called likeFlag and it is a tinyint. A regular int would work too and i believe a bool type would also. ** also I didnt show you mysqli way of doing it. I will leave that up to you.

Comment: what if i click again the button to unlike the post??..correct me if im wrong..

`if ($action == "toggleLike") {
    UpdateLikeFlag($id);
  }else{
    unlikeflag($id);
}

 UpdateLikeFlag($id){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE yourTable SET likeFlag = 1 - likeFlag WHERE id = '$id'");    
  }
unlikeflag($id){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE yourTable SET likeFlag = 1 - likeFlag WHERE id = '$id'");  
}`

Comment: No you dont need to do that. In the query is where it will flip the number.
Check the above process.php for the details. I have added the explaination there. This is effectively a toggle. No need for if statements.

Comment: ohhhh i think were misleading here..let me update my post sorry i didn't include my table field..i understand your code but i think it will not fit with my table fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".btn ").click(function(){ 
   $('.boxcoracao .coracao', this).toggleClass("ativo");
   // make an ajax call here to send the data to the server and save it in database
});
```

If condition be like:

```
var selection = '';
if( $(this).val() == 'like' )
{
    selection = 'liked';
}
else
{
    selection = 'like';
}
```

pass this variable `selection` in `ajax()` call.

and on page reload check the status from database to show like / unlike icon respectively.

Comment: can you provide an example of the if statement for this?.cause i dont really have an idea on how to do it when the user unlike the button

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include an if statement inside the click function.

```
$(".btn ").click(function(){ 
   $('.boxcoracao .coracao', this).toggleClass("ativo"); 

  if( $(this).hasClass("ativo") ) {
    // the query to exicute if the class has been added
  }
  else {
    // the query to exicute if the class has been removed
  }
});
```