# Adding post to favorite with PDO and SQL

Tags: php, jquery, favorites

I have implemented **Add to favorite** using `PHP` and `SQL`, So that user can save there favorite post in database and **Remove form favorite**

**I used below code :**

```
    function checkFavorite($mbid, $pid, $conn) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE memberID=:mid AND id=:id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':mid' => $mbid, ':id' => $pid));
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($count == 0) {
            echo "<div class='button' data-method='Like' data-user-id=" . $mbid . " data-director-id=" . $pid . "><i class='mi' id=" . $pid . ">favorite_border</i>Add Favorite</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='button' data-method='Unlike' data-user-id=" . $mbid . " data-director-id=" . $pid . "><i class='mi mi_sml text-danger' id=" . $pid . ">favorite</i>Remove Favorite</div>";
        }
    }

    $email = 'user@user.com';
    // Query to get the user_id
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT memberID FROM members WHERE email = :email AND active="Yes" ');
    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $mbid = $row['memberID'];

    $pid = '4';
    // Query to Get the Director ID
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE id =:id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $pid));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $row) {

        echo "<p>Director: " . $row['tit'] . "</p> ";
        $fav_image = checkFavorite($mbid, $pid, $conn);
        echo "Favorite? : " . $fav_image . "";
    }
```

**Script**

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.button').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const user_id = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
                const director_id = $(this).attr('data-director-id');
                const method = $(this).attr('data-method');
                if (method === "Like") {
                    $(this).attr('method', 'Unlike'); // Change the div method attribute to Unlike
                    $('#' + director_id).replaceWith('<i class="mi mi_sml text-danger" id="' + director_id + '">favorite</i>Remove Favorite'); // Replace the image with the liked button
                } else {
                    $(this).attr('method', 'Like');
                    $('#' + director_id).replaceWith('<i class="mi mi_sml" id="' + director_id + '">favorite_border</i>Add Favorite');
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'favs.php', // Call favs.php to update the database
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {user_id: user_id, director_id: director_id, method: method},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

[image]

When you look at image you can see

1. `replaceWith` doesn't change button and text
2. And in **XHR** request all request method are send as `method="like"`

but when request is send the data are saved and no error in console.

So how do i change text for `Add to favorite` to `Remove from favorite` when clicked in button.

Comment: You only want to change text *add to favorite* to *remove from favorite* ?

Comment: yes `<div class='button' data-method='Like'.....` it does not change when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need! Here is what I used in a demo a few years ago, you can edit to your requirements.

Add your update url to texts like me and remove.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".like button").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('btn')) {
            $(this).html('remove').toggleClass('btn mybtn');
        } else {
            $(this).html('Like me').toggleClass('mybtn btn');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.mybtn {
    color: red;
}
.btn {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like">
    <p>Like</p>
    <button class="btn">Like me</button>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Netmaster/4075f9ne/6/)

**UPDATE :** Sorry I was away from pc! it should be very simple to inject in your codes:

I guess your php codes are In Your `favs.php` I did try like this for response in `favs.php` `echo 'response';`

Html button! you can change to your class :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".button").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 const user_id = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
 const director_id = $(this).attr('data-director-id');
 const method = $(this).attr('data-method'); 
        if (method === "Like") {
            $(this).html('<i class="mi mi_sml text-danger" id="' + director_id + '">favorite</i>Remove Favorite').toggleClass('button mybtn');
            //Change remove text to your i class
        } else {
            $(this).html('<i class="mi mi_sml" id="' + director_id + '">favorite_border</i>Add Favorite').toggleClass('mybtn button');
            //Change Like me text to your i class 
            //you can remove or edit class mybtn in both remove and like
        }
 $.ajax({
  url: 'favs.php',
  type: 'GET', // type not method
  data: {user_id: user_id, director_id: director_id, method: method},
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
   alert(data);
  }
 });
});
});
```

```css
.mybtn {
    color: red;
}
.btn {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like">
    <p>Like</p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Like me</button>
</div>
```

I might have some mistakes like class name etc... you can edit and make it suitable for your requirements.

I tested its working fine. [SOLVED](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48682405#48682405)

Comment: Great this is what am looking, and how do i implement this in my script

Comment: Replace `if (method === "Like") {` to the function in answer. and add your update button in `html('remove')`. example `html('<i class="mi mi_sml text-danger" id="' + director_id + '">favorite</i>)`

Comment: @Zelay'da do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/49nbth0d/

Comment: @sanojlawrence See this edited your codes https://jsfiddle.net/23ks5uzL/ and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132578/12890815

Comment: @Dlk can you update with my `HTML` provided in question

Comment: When i try your code `data-method='like'` is not changing to `data-method='Unlike'` when clicking on button. that's the main issue am facing in both code.

Comment: Change this `<div class='button'` to `<div class='like'` or to  `<div class='like button'`

Comment: @Dlk yes i did i just tried with this `$(".button button").click(function (e)`  my problem is `data-method='like'` is not changing to `data-method='Unlike'`